# Ubuntu installer skips first installation type page

Tags: dual-boot, usb-installation

When trying to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 7000 series laptop I encountered 2 problems, the first one being that the page where the option to erase and reinstall Ubuntu did not appear, and instead skipped to the page you get after choosing the "something else" option, I did some research but didn't find much, so I just tried to install it anyway, the installer then gets stuck on "saving installed packages" with the last message being "step_before = stepUserInfo".
I've installed ubuntu before, and I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this problem.

I'm using Rufus to make the USB bootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my original installation usb, and it worked, it seems it had something to do with either the way I installed Ubuntu to the usb or the USB itself, the one that didn't work was a SanDisk Ultra, while the one that did was an imation nano pmap.